# How to safely type hierarchical metadata objects in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'd like to create some constants that define a hierarchy of categories with subcategories. These will then be re-used to render different pages in an application, but by defining them as constants in one place I can quickly scaffold pages.

For example, given categories like:

```
const CATEGORIES = [
  {
    id: 'diet',
    name: 'Diet',
    color: 'green',
  },
  {
    id: 'energy',
    name: 'Energy',
    color: 'yellow',
  },
  ...
]
```

But now I'd like to have these objects be typed with TypeScript. I could use the `as const` syntax to infer a category type of:

```
{
  id: 'diet' | 'energy' | ...
  name: 'Diet' | 'Energy' | ...
  color: 'green' | 'yellow' | ...
}
```

Which is great. (Although I don't really need the `name/color` specificity.)

But then when defining subcategories I run into a problem...

```
const SUBCATEGORIES = [
  {
    id: 'red_meat',
    category: 'diet',
    name: 'Red Meat',
    emoji: '',
  },
  ...
]
```

If I use `as const` on the `SUBCATEGORIES` object then there's no type safety for the `category` key. I could easily misspell `'deit'` and never know.

But if I use a declaration like:

```
const SUBCATEGORIES: Array<{
  id: string
  category: typeof CATEGORIES[number]['id']
  ...
}> = [
  ...
]
```

Then I can no longer infer the `id` key strings from subcategories later, because they will have a type of `string` instead.

---

Is there a way to define these sorts of metadata structures in TypeScript to have some a middle-ground between `as const` and defined types? How can I get the `id` keys to be inferred as constants while the rest is typed?

I'd be open to defining them as objects instead of arrays, but I can't seem to figure out a way that that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this I usually make a helper function which *verifies* that a value is assignable to a type without *widening* it to that type.  Assuming `CATEGORIES` looks like

```
const CATEGORIES = [
  {
    id: 'diet',
    name: 'Diet',
    color: 'green',
  },
  {
    id: 'energy',
    name: 'Energy',
    color: 'yellow',
  },
  // ...
] as const;
```

then the helper function `asSubcategories` could look like this:

```
const asSubcategories = <S extends ReadonlyArray<{
  id: string;
  category: typeof CATEGORIES[number]['id'];
  name: string;
  emoji: string;
}>>(s: S) => s;
```

Here `asSubcategories` literally just returns its input without changing it, but it only accepts arguments of generic type `S` that is assignable to the type you care about.  Then you call it like this:

```
const SUBCATEGORIES = asSubcategories([
  {
    id: 'red_meat',
    category: 'diet',
    name: 'Red Meat',
    emoji: '',
  },
  //...
] as const);
```

Since there's no error, you didn't misspell the `category`, and the type of `SUBCATEGORIES` is still

```
/* const SUBCATEGORIES: readonly [{
    readonly id: "red_meat";
    readonly category: "diet";
    readonly name: "Red Meat";
    readonly emoji: "";
}] */
```

If you *do* misspell things, you should get a big error:

```
const BADSUBCATEGORIES = asSubcategories([
  {
    id: 'read_met',
    category: 'deit',
    name: 'Read Met',
    emoji: '',
  },
  //...
] as const); // error!!
/* Types of property 'category' are incompatible.
   Type '"deit"' is not assignable to type '"diet" | "energy"'
  */
```

Yay!  There are ways to use helper functions to narrow some properties while widening others, but the above should hopefully be enough to help you proceed. Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwgQQCoFEDiB5ASgSRQZRgF4YBtAKBhgG9KqYBLAEwC4YByJhgUynYBo6VMAEMAttzbsAIjz6D6MUABsQAJykBzNd25gBdAL4KaQxqw57uazQE8Di0RKkow1uw-or1U292WqAO6exnQA9GEwAHQx5AC6MCIQSuDQANzk5KCQsEn4AK4ARsAiUNya6jzJJAA8hNwAHmVgTMlY3CJM4Mq2CGpqIrY1tFTMbNBqDGCaGVQlZRVqtmxQtgAO3CAAZvDI6Nh4+KRg+WKF1nGk7MzscbMwTpIwE1MzdNxiIABWDONQk9MMoYAHzAgAUEDY+AAlMRgc8MllUrB8ABVABCiFQmFwBGIiQgBWKpXKlW4EDBFCoI3oYw4OiYAH0JKUBDAzPNSUspFxeJ5hOInux2kwYABZDryMwfb6-DiAPg3AJa7IRMERiUXiBJSOWhGTCACptdAYGjMXscYc2DpOt1bGQaVRrV0wD1zGwAEQM5mS933R0dZ2uzmLZYwd28qC+sxO20PQUekXin1+mAxl12mU-D1KqOGBL6sKZbLG9EIaSmrH7XGEEh5IrBskUqmmRR09hO71SxQN7kcJjcBhd+iPKTtTpJodUTNy9iAHg3ACr7KvCYXVmqSRqgupgERg1jU6gAhAfyAaYEh1uSYNsYGt9xs1KsOD37IkdIwwKAxGtSgxCspuBq9DnhsHDhgOkbsIwyRgCAuQQBADCaKIf7cDAUAgGhF6gRG7owAAPmGVg2LY7rsHQBbkEAA)